# Unix: Count occurrences of similar entries in first column, sum the second column

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with two columns of data, I would like to count the occurrence of similarities in the first column. When two similar entries in the first column are matched, I would like to also sum the value of the second column of the two matched entries.

Example list:

```
2013-11-13-03 1
2013-11-13-06 1
2013-11-13-13 2
2013-11-13-13 1
2013-11-13-15 1
2013-11-13-15 1
2013-11-13-15 1
2013-11-13-17 1
2013-11-13-23 1
2013-11-14-01 1
2013-11-14-04 6
2013-11-14-07 1
2013-11-14-08 1
2013-11-14-09 1
2013-11-14-09 1
```

I would like the output to read similar to the following

```
2013-11-13-03 1 1
2013-11-13-06 1 1
2013-11-13-13 2 3
2013-11-13-15 3 3
2013-11-13-17 1 1
2013-11-13-23 1 1
2013-11-14-01 1 1
2013-11-14-04 1 6
2013-11-14-07 1 1
2013-11-14-08 1 1
2013-11-14-09 2 2
```

Column 1 is the matched columns from the earlier example column 1, column 2 is the count of matches of column 1 from the earlier example (1 if no other matches), column 3 is the sum of column 2 from the matched column 1 entries from the earlier example. Anyone have any tips on completing this using awk or a mixture of uniq and awk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quickie with `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk '
{
    counts[$1]++;     # Increment count of lines.
    totals[$1] += $2; # Accumulate sum of second column.
}
END {
    # Iterate over all first-column values.
    for (x in counts) {
        print x, counts[x], totals[x];
    }
}
' file.txt | sort
```

You can skip the `sort` if you don't care about the order of output lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here a pure Bash solution

```
$ cat t
2013-11-13-03 1
2013-11-13-06 1
2013-11-13-13 2
2013-11-13-13 1
2013-11-13-15 1
2013-11-13-15 1
2013-11-13-15 1
2013-11-13-17 1
2013-11-13-23 1
2013-11-14-01 1
2013-11-14-04 6
2013-11-14-07 1
2013-11-14-08 1
2013-11-14-09 1
2013-11-14-09 1
$ declare -A SUM CNT
$ while read ts vl; do (( SUM[$ts]=+$vl )) ; (( CNT[$ts]++ )); done < t
$ for i in "${!CNT[@]}"; do   echo "$i ${CNT[$i]} ${SUM[$i]} "; done | sort
2013-11-13-03 1 1 
2013-11-13-06 1 1 
2013-11-13-13 2 3 
2013-11-13-15 3 3 
2013-11-13-17 1 1 
2013-11-13-23 1 1 
2013-11-14-01 1 1 
2013-11-14-04 1 6 
2013-11-14-07 1 1 
2013-11-14-08 1 1 
2013-11-14-09 2 2
```